# Reload Table in DataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

I have ajax function which can insert/update records and I'm using DataTable.

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable(); // Working...
```

But when I add `ajax`

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({

    "processing": true,

    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_list')?>",
        "type": "POST"
    },
});
```

I got an popup error says:
[CLICK HERE...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsWlp.png)

Anyone can help about this error?

Comment: The Json objects created in your datatable doesn't match the signature of your service.

Comment: If you go to https://datatables.net/tn/1, as noted in the error in your screenshot, the page gives you a very specific reason for this issue as well as steps to pinpoint your error and correct it. Have you tried those things yet?

Comment: I tried it, but it's nothing